# Load as default the current date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html

How can I load as default the current date -30 days in the Initial Date field and the current date in the Final Date Field using the datepicker class of the bootstrap?

Example:

[image]

Comment: please share your working

Comment: You need to share your code. We can't do anything with images.

Comment: there are many bootstrap-compatible datepickers. Which one are you using? Shows your code. Anyway, whichever it is, I would guess it provides a way to initialise the date. So all you have to do is get the current date from javascript, subtract 30 days from it, and then pass it to the datepicker. What did you try so far?

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following snippet.

Current date:

```
'update', new Date()
```

30 days before

```
"setDate", "-1m"
```

-1m = minus 1 month from the current date.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
  }).datepicker('update', new Date());


  $('#datepicker2').datepicker({

  }).datepicker("setDate", "-1m");
});
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#datepicker {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

#datepicker>span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#datepicker2 {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

#datepicker2>span:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


<label>Date initial: </label>
<div id="datepicker2" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>

<label>Date final: </label>
<div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
  <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: this took a bit of effort to find out how to set date to one month back, appreciate for an upvote